# Javascript: Nested for loops to create a directory tree in VMware vCenter

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

To start, as you can tell via my code, I am not a programmer and I do not know javascript.  I am actually working with VMware Orchestrator (which is based on Rhino javascript engine, I belive) to create some workflows.  Please explain any answers in detail.

I am trying to create a workflow that will create a directory tree in vCenter.

Concept:
Basically I am trying to run nested for loops for each tier of the tree calling a global tree.

Problem:
The 1st for loop works and creates the folder "Dev".  The second for loop does not work with an error message:

```
[2013-06-27 19:16:16.219] [I] Building folder Dev
[2013-06-27 19:16:16.474] [I] Built directory: Dev
[2013-06-27 19:16:16.476] [I] Building folder Servers
[2013-06-27 19:16:16.480] [I] TypeError: Cannot find function createFolder in object Dev. (Workflow:TEST_TNG_New_Site_Folder_Structure / Scriptable task (item2)#36)
```

I think it has to do with JavaScript not being able to call a global function into a nested object (I am not a programmer and do not know JavaScript so don't shoot me on this)

Code: (will clean this up once I get it working)

```
var folderBase = ["Dev","DMZ","Prod","UAT"];

var folderT1 = ["Servers","Workstations"];

var folderT2 = ["Windows","Linux"];

var folderT3 = ["Repo1","Repo2","Repo3","Repo4"];

var folderT4 = ["T1","T2","T3"];



// Create the folderBase level of folders

for (var i=0,l=folderBase.length; i<l; i++) {

    var rootFolder = parentFolder;

    buildFolderTree(folderBase[i]);

        // Create the folderT1 level of folders

        for (var j=0, l=folderT1.length; j<l; j++) {

            var rootFolder = folderBase[i];

            buildFolderTree(folderT1[j]);

                // Create the folderT2 level of folders

                for (var k=0, l=folderT2.length; k<l; k++) {

                    var rootFolder = folderT1[j];

                    buildFolderTree(folderT2[k]);

                        // Create the folderT3 level of folders

                        for (var x=0, l=folderT3.length; x<l; x++) {

                            var rootFolder = folderT2[k];

                            buildFolderTree(folderT3[x]);

                                // Create the folderT4 level of folders

                                for (var y=0, l=folderT4.length; y<l; y++) {

                                    var rootFolder = folderT3[x];

                                    buildFolderTree(folderT4[y]);

                                    }

                            }

                    }       

            }

    }



function buildFolderTree(folderName) {

        System.log("Building folder " + folderName);

        rootFolder.createFolder(folderName);

        System.log("Built directory: " + folderName);

    }
```

Comment: One problem you have is that JavaScript has only function level scope, so all your loop index and length variables need to have different names. The length variables in particular are all called 'l' in your sample, they should have different names like 'il', 'jl', etc (or whatever you choose).

Answer (score 1):

Here was the solution.  Apparently it was not to do with nested for loops and global objects but more to do with object reference (I still do not fully understand it).

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CODE: Javascript                                                         //
// TITLE: BuildFolderTree                                                   //
// AUTHOR: Brandt Winchell                                                  //
// COLLABORATOR: robrtb12                                                   //
// VERSION: 1.0                                                             //
// DATE MODIFIED: June 29, 2013                                             //
// PURPOSE:  Build a directory tree in vCenter VM & Template section        //
// ADDITIONAL INFO: !!Root folder must be created manually before           //
// running this code!!                                                      //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DECLARE VARIABLES
var folderBase = ["Dev","DMZ","Prod","UAT"];//base folders
var folderT1 = ["Servers","Workstations"]; //sub-folders of $folderBase
var folderT2 = ["Windows","Linux"]; //sub-folders of $folderT1
var folderT3 = ["Repo1","Repo2","Repo3","Repo4"]; //sub-folders of $folderT2
var folderT4 = ["T1","T2","T3"]; //sub-folder of $folderT3
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// GLOBAL EXCEPTION CATCH FOR NULL INPUT VARIABLES
if (parentFolder == null) {
    throw "REFERENCE ERROR: $parentFolder IS NULL!!";
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// BUILD THE DIRECTORY TREE
// create the $folderBase level of directory
for (var i=0; i<folderBase.length; i++) {
    var newBaseFolder = buildFolderTree(parentFolder, folderBase[i]);
    // Create the $folderT1 level of folders
    for (var j=0; j<folderT1.length; j++) {
        var newT1Folder = buildFolderTree(newBaseFolder, folderT1[j]);
        // Create the $folderT2 level of folders
        for (var k=0; k<folderT2.length; k++) {
            var newT2Folder = buildFolderTree(newT1Folder, folderT2[k]);
            // Create the $folderT3 level of folders
            for (var x=0; x<folderT3.length; x++) {
                var newT3Folder = buildFolderTree(newT2Folder, folderT3[x]);
                // Create the $folderT4 level of folders
                for (var y=0; y<folderT4.length; y++) {
                    var newT4Folder = buildFolderTree(newT3Folder, folderT4[y]);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// BUILD FUNCTION $buildFolderTree
function buildFolderTree(parentFolderObj, folderName) {
  System.log("Building folder " + folderName);
  var newFolder = parentFolderObj.createFolder(folderName);
  System.log("Built directory: " + folderName);
  return newFolder;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```